# Building multiple page React applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm experimenting with React in hopes that it will be a good framework to base one of my larger projects on. As I move away from the SPA type React testing applications I've been doing I'm wondering what the best practices are for developing multi page applications.

With React Router it seems as though you'd do something similar to this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/path1" component={App1}>
            <Route path="/subpath1" component={Layout1} />
            <Route path="/subpath2" component={Layout2} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/path2" component={App2}>
            <Route path="/subpath1" component={Layout3} />
            <Route path="/subpath2" component={Layout4} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And make your ENTIRE app client sided.

The other method I can think of would be to have your directory structure intact and have something similar to the above within each of your undex files (would of course have to configure Webpack for multiple entry points and output bundles).

So, is there a sort of "standard" in place for how React developers "should" be doing things?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your goal. Yes there are "standards" and "best practices", but if there is one thing that react.js should teach us it's that we should experiment.

I usually opt for routing everything together until you clearly have a project that needs a clear separation. Your goal is not really clearly stated yet. Could you give more information?